# Cannot run fsck on broken FAT after "unsafe" device removal

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

I've got an SD card I've accidentally removed without unmounting on an Android phone. After this, the card shows up as having files with garbage names and dates. Seems, that FAT got broken but I cannot run fsck on this drive:

```
$ sudo dosfsck -n /dev/sdb
dosfsck 3.0.7, 24 Dec 2009, FAT32, LFN
Logical sector size (64543 bytes) is not a multiple of the physical sector size.
```

How I can work around this error and recover the data?

Answer (score 5):

While it doesn't help to repair the file system, the error actually means that you have to specify partition and not disk to fsck:

```
$ sudo dosfsck -n /dev/sdb1
```

as opposed to

```
$ sudo dosfsck -n /dev/sdb
```

Comment: What if it is done over a file, say `usb.img`, and cannot mount it?